# Deserializing Json to C# list

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize JSON to C# list. I have the Jquery code as,

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn_check").click(function () {
            var str="";
            x = $("#frm").serializeArray();
            $("#Label1").empty();
            $.each(x, function (i, field) {
              //  $("#Label1").append(field.name + ":" + field.value + " ");

                str = str + field.name + ":" + field.value + " ";

            });
            var jsonstr=JSON.stringify(str);            });
    });
```

after stringify, I get something weird as jsonstr=
__VIEWSTATE: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 __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:172284EE __EVENTVALIDATION:/wEWNAKauo6nDAK5rJ0YAp7D/4IGAoPa4e0LAujww9gBAs2HpsMHArKeiK4NApe16pgDAvzLzIMJApH2i8IBAvaM7qwHAp7Dv7UBAp7Dq9oIAp7Dl/8PAp7Dg6QHAp7Dj6IEAp7D+8YLAp7D5+sCAp7D05AKAp7Dn9wLAp7Di4EDAoPaoaAHAoPajcUOAoPa+ekFAoPa5Y4NAoPa8YwKAoPa3bEBAoPaydYIAoPatfsPAoPagccBAoPa7esIAujwg4sNAujw768EAujw29QLAujwx/kCAujw0/cPAujwv5wHAujwq8EOAujwl+YFAujw47EHAujwz9YOAs2H5vUCAs2H0poKAs2Hvr8BAs2HquQIAs2HtuIFAs2HoocNAs2HjqwEAs2H+tALAs2HxpwNAs2HssEEAvCFnqIPppJbhAvF8AzSoMd/uZfiRXpzWu0= **check_0:on check_1:on check_2:on check_3:on check_4:on check_5:on check_6:on check_7:on check_8:on check_9:on check_10:on check_11:on check_12:on check_13:on check_14:on check_15:on check_16:on check_17:on check_18:on check_19:on check_20:on check_21:on check_22:on check_23:on check_24:on check_25:on check_26:on check_27:on check_28:on check_29:on check_30:on check_31:on check_32:on check_33:on check_34:on check_35:on check_36:on check_37:on check_38:on check_39:on check_40:on check_41:on check_42:on check_43:on check_44:on check_45:on check_46:on check_47:on check_48:on check_49:on**

check_0 to check_1 are the dynamically created checkboxes and I want to get their values in C# as list or in any form to interpret and push them into Database.

asp.net:

```
<form id="frm" runat="server">

    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_seat" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhdr_seat" runat="server">
         checkboxes are dynamically created here
       </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <br />
        <button id="btn_check" type="button">Serialize form values</button>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_submit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  OnClick="btn_submit_Click" />
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />

    </asp:Panel>

</form>
```

picture:[image]

C# code:

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
class abc // some class
{   
    protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Test> myDeserializedObjList = (List<Test>)   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request["jsonstr"], typeof(List<Test>));
    }
 }
```

the above code I got it from [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C).
But on running this code, I am getting an exception that "str" as "null". How to push the label1 or str to server side? Help me please.

Comment: Use HiddenField to push code to server side...

Comment: Voting to close as it is unlikely to help any future visitors (and old enough for reputation to be set in stone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQUERY:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn_check").click(function () {
            var str = "";
            x = $("#frm").serializeArray();
             str = JSON.stringify(x);
           // $("#HiddenField1").Value(str);
            $('#<%=hdnSelectedTicket.ClientID %>').val(str);
           <%-- $('#<%=hdnSelectedTicket.ClientID %>')--%>

        });
    });
```

ASP.NET:

```
<form id="frm" runat="server">
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedTicket"  runat="server" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_seat" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhdr_seat" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        <br />
        <button id="btn_check" type="button">Serialize form values</button>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_submit_Click" />
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />


    </asp:Panel>

</form>
```

C#:

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string a = hdnSelectedTicket.Value;
        List<Test> myDeserializedObjList = (List<Test>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject    (hdnSelectedTicket.Value, typeof(List<Test>));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste more code? It's hard to find any issues from the limited source code.
 You may send the `str` to server using an ajax request:

`$.get('your url', {str: str})`

By the way, It seems the `str` is not a valid JSON string. `str = JSON.strigify(x)` will stringify the object to a JSON string.

---

Try this:
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn_check").click(function () {
        var x = $("#frm").serializeArray();
        $("#Label1").empty().text(JSON.stringify(x));
    });
});
```

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
class abc // some class
{
    protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    List<Test> myDeserializedObjList = (List<Test>) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Label1.Text, typeof(List<Test>));
    }
}
```

```

Comment: Sin, this is more a comment, then an answer.

Comment: any further details needed?